# Constant variable cannot be template parameter for reference, but non-const can

Tags: c++, templates

There is this code:

```
#include <iostream>

template<const double& f>
void fun5(){
    std::cout << f << std::endl;
} 

//const double dddd = 5.0; error: ‘dddd’ cannot appear in a constant-expression
//however it works for extern const double dddd = 5.0;

double dddd = 5.0; // works

int main() 
{ 
    fun5<dddd>();
    return 0;
}
```

`const double dddd` doesn't work as template parameter (however `extern const double dddd` works). `double dddd` works, but it is not constant. What is difference between `extern const double` and `const double` variables defined in global scope?

Comment: I think this is a duplicate, we had that not too long ago. The gist is, that `const` global changes the linkage to internal or something, and template parameters needed external linkage before C++11.

Comment: so 'double dddd = 5.0;' has external linkage too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`const` gives variables internal linkage by default, while both `extern` and non-const do not. Internal linkage symbols are expressly prohibited from being template parameters by the standard (pre-C++11, I know a few things changed there).

Answer (score 1):

When you put in the expression:

```
const double dddd = 5.0;
```

Effectively you are aliasing dddd to be 5.0 and there is no variable there at all, it can be used as a constant and therefore has no address. You would be able to pass it to a function that takes a const reference because the parameter itself is a variable, i.e. it has a space on the stack, you can take its address. You cannot do that with a constant. There is no &dddd in your code.

If you make it extern, it does actually turn into a "proper" variable that occupies memory and has an address. It is immutable but it is not a constant.

(Essentially the compiler is allowed to eliminate dddd and substitute it for 5.0 anywhere in the code. This is `internal linkage`).